# OpenGL ES - get 2D pixel coordinate from camera position

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, opengl-es

I'm working with OpenGL ES (IOS) and OpenCV. I would like to know if there is a way to get 2D pixel coordinate from a GLKMatrix4 camera position ?

Indeed, I have a specific 3D object displayed with OpenGL which has only its size and its camera pose and I would like to convert it into the OpenCV reference Coordinate i.e 2D pixel.

More precisely, I have an IOS app and I stream the camera color. This stream is displayed with OpenGL on my Ipad. On this display, I have a specific overlay which is a 3D object. At the same time, I do some some detection with OpenCV. Now, I would like to link the result of my detection thank to OpenCV in my frame (It's a rectangle draw) with the 3D object but for this one, I have only its camera position and its size.

I know the content of a 4x4 camera pose but I did not find any information about how I could convert it (if it is possible) to a 2D coordinate.

So briefly : 
Input : A 2D rectangle (get only 2D coordinate) and an 3D object (get only its camera position)

Is there a way ? Could you please help me ?

Thank

Comment: Are you looking to get a pixel that is represented by the matrix or a pixel that is represented by a vector multiplied by a matrix? Explain what exactly is your input.

Comment: I've just edited my post. Actually yes, I would like to have the 2D coordinate (pixel) from my camera pose (Matrix 4x4) of my 3D object. Thank Matic.

Comment: This was originally posted on [Robotics](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38763529/42473) but migrated after it was double posted here.

Answer (score 1):

To get the onscreen projection of the vector you only need to multiply it by the matrix you are using in the openGL. The 3rd coordinate is simply discarded and is used only for the depth buffer (also interpolations but it really doesn't matter here).

In openGL the coordinate of the drawn pixel you will get by multiplying it with a matrix will be normalized to a coordinate system in range `[-1,1]` in all axises. That means a pixel that is on most top-left of the screen/view will have a coordinate `(-1,1)`, top-right `(1,1)`, center `(0,0)`... Now corresponding to the buffer pixels this value must be denormalized:

You need to have the buffer `width` and `height` so then the pixel position is `bufferX = ((x+1)/2.0) * width` and `bufferY = ((y+1)/2.0) * height`. The results are floating values so you need to either round them to integers or typecast them. I have no idea which is done by the openGL though.

Comment: Do not forget to check if the coordinate is actually inside the buffer...

Comment: Thank for your reply but I have only the camera position of my object, that's it. So do I need to decompose this camera position ?

Comment: If I understand this correctly you only need to multiply the zero vector with the matrix then. Or you could probably just take the transformation vector of the matrix (4th row) and use it as a result.

Comment: Yes Okey, suppose I take the 4th row for getting my position  float posX =cubePose.m30;float posY = cubePose.m31;posZ =_slamState.cubePose.m32; my coordinate seems to be between - 1 and 1 (OpenGL coordinate), so how I could recover the screen coordinate (for example 640x420) ? Thank

Comment: Are you sure that m30, 31.. are correct? Is it not m40, 41..? Anyway you only need the 2 coordinates to which you apply the transform as described above. You need to first normalize them to [0,1] by using (x+1)/2 and then scale them to the buffer size so (x+1)/2*bufferWidth. The size of the buffer should be accessible through openGL API if you do not have them yet.

Comment: Thank ! It sounds good but I did not have to normalize between -1 and 1 (otherwise the result is not coherent). I don't understand why...
Concerning the matrix, yes this is a 4x4 matrix but which begins at index 0 (so 0, 1, 2, 3) and 3 is the last one. And one last thing. I came accros another formula which is : u = fx * x' + cx
//v = fy * y' + cy ? Why not using this one ? 
thank again for your reply.

Comment: I can not decipher what those equations are since I can't know what those parameters represent. What is the final result you are using now?

Comment: It's working but it's not that perfect...But I thing because there is a problem with my OpenGL coordinate. It seems not to be like [- 1 1]
Thank anyway

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using GLKit types and math, try the function [`GLKMathProject`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/glkit/1488726-glkmathproject?language=objc) to convert from 3D model space to viewport (window/pixel 2D) space, and [`GLKMathUnproject`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/glkit/1488720-glkmathunproject?language=objc) if you also need the other way around. You'll need the (same) modelview and projection matrices that you're (presumably) passing to a shader for drawing your scene.